# How to adjust ListBox items height to fit the text in Firemonkey (android)?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm using this code to add an item to a listbox, but I can't figure out how to dynamically resize the height of the item to fit the text:

```
procedure TmForm.AddItemBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
  Item.Parent := SomeListBox;
  Item.StyleLookup := 'listboxitemstyle';
  Item.Text :=
              'Pe cararea lunga scurta se ducea un om venind, si-n tacerea lui ' +
              'profunda se auzea borborosind. Cantr-o noapte intunecoasa soarel' +
              'e lucea pe cer, iara eu cu barca in casa ma plimbam ca un boier.';
  Item.WordWrap := true;
  Item.StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily] + [TStyledSetting.ssStyle] + [TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  Item.Font.Size := 14;
end;
```

I tried using the code from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430290/how-to-adjust-button-size-to-fit-the-text-in-delphi-firemonkey) (modified for TListBoxItem), but it didn't work.

**Edit:** The height of the ListBoxItem can be set by just adding `Item.Height := 100;` at the end of the code above, but I need to know the height of text to decide what size the ListBoxItem needs to be, so to clarify my question, how do I get the height of the text in the list box item?

Answer (score 1):

Pop your resizing code in the OnApplyStyleLookup event.

Written off the top of my head and way past bedtime:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBoxItemApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  O := (Sender as TListBoxItem).FindStyleResource('text');
  if O is TText then
    (Sender as TListBoxItem).Height := (O as TText).Height;
end;
```

You will, of course, need to set the event for every item you create.

Comment: I added to my code Item.OnApplyStyleLookup := ListBoxItemApplyStyleLookup; and the code you posted but the results are the same, actually the code in the ListBoxItemApplyStyleLookup is never reached.

Comment: We cannot manually set Height for ListItem this way, because for mobile platforms firemonkey in style fixes height of item, so you can not directly change height.

Comment: @Yaroslav, that's only for certain controls such as edits and buttons. There are other controls where the height can be set manually.

Comment: @ioan, Is the item actually being displayed? The style is only set once a control appears on screen.

Comment: @ioan. My tests show you need to set the event handler as the very first thing you do after creating the item It will then work fine.

Comment: After playing with this, it appears that the text never word wraps properly even if you manually set a larger height for the item. Either I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug there somewhere.

Comment: @MikeSutton Yeah, doesn't work for me either. I think I'm going to move away from the ListBox and use the ScrollBox with my own custom items.

Comment: I'm having similar issues where setting item height does not work in XE7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436085/hide-empty-space-behind-invisible-list-box-items

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mike Sutton, it can be done `OnApplyStyleLookup` event.
I do it using a `TTextLayout` :

```
uses 
... ,FMX.TextLayout;

procedure TfrmForm1.ListBoxItem1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  myLayout: TTextLayout;
  aPoint: TPointF;
begin

  myLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  myLayout.BeginUpdate;

  // Setting the layout MaxSize
  aPoint.X := ListBoxItem1.Width;
  aPoint.Y := TfrmForm1.Height;
  myLayout.MaxSize := aPoint;

  myLayout.Text := ListBoxItem1.Text;
  myLayout.WordWrap := True ;
  myLayout.Font := ListBoxItem1.Font;
  myLayout.HorizontalAlign := ListBoxItem1.TextSettings.HorzAlign;
  myLayout.VerticalAlign := ListBoxItem1.TextSettings.VertAlign;
  myLayout.Padding := ListBoxItem1.Padding;
  // set other properties as needed        

  myLayout.EndUpdate;

  ListBoxItem1.Height := Trunc(myLayout.TextHeight) + 3 ; // +3px to be sure to see entire text

end;
```

Note that `MaxSize` is limitating. For example, `aPoint.Y` will limit the final `TextHeight`. You should set it large because, whatever `TextHeight` should be, if `myLayout.TextHeight` is larger than `myLayout.MaxSize.Y` then `myLayout.TextHeight` will be set to `myLayout.MaxSize.Y`.

[Here's a list](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.TextLayout.TTextLayout_Properties) of `TTextLayout` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Mike Sutton's code, improved and tested by me. Works for case of an Item with a Detail text (.ItemData.Detail). The variant with TextLayout did not work for me.

This code is tested for Windows and Android application.

```
procedure TTestForm.ListBoxItem1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var item: TListBoxItem absolute Sender;

  function CalcHeight( SubStyle: String ): Single;
  var Obj: TFMXObject; T: TText absolute Obj;
  begin
    Obj := item.FindStyleResource(SubStyle);
    if Obj is TText
    then Result := T.Canvas.TextHeight(T.Text)
                 + T.Margins.Top + T.Margins.Bottom
                 + T.Padding.Top + T.Padding.Bottom
    else Result := 0;
  end;

begin
  item.Height := CalcHeight('text')
               + CalcHeight('detail');
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are one important thing about changing size of control: **"For mobile platform, firemonkey fix height and with some controls"**. Because:

1. UI Style Guidline for each platform define rules about size of standart controls.
2. Firemonkey uses raster style, so you cannot change some control size, because you will lost a quality of view

However, you can remove this contraints. Look at the my solution this (Auto translated with Google):  [Can not increase the height TProgressBar](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ru&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/38-android-ne-poluchaetsia-uvelichit-vysotu-tprogressbar/)

This article about TProgressBar, But you can use this approach also for a TListBoxItem.

Comment: There isn't a FixedHeight field for the ListBoxItem and the height of the item can be set bu just adding Item.Height := 95; in the code, but I need to know the height of the text to know what value to set the ListBoxItem height.