# Delphi Rio - buttons sized to their text

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

Delphi Rio 10.3 Android project

When the size of a button gets small enough that it cannot display the full text, it truncates it. For example, a "Disconnect" button will label itself "Disco..."

What code will change the width of the button to the minimum width required to display the complete text?

Comment: Doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/q/18430290/62576 answer this question?

Comment: That solution was marked as working for Delphi XE4. I will try to adapt it to Rio.

Comment: There are lots of questions marked as working for Delphi 7 that still apply to Rio, too. :-) I don't know if it will work for Rio or not, as I don't use Firemonkey for anything serious at this point, so I didn't close it as a duplicate. It's worth taking a look at to see if it solves your problem, though.